# If you are moved to a location with a clue do you pick it up?

Tags: arkham-horror

In Arkham Horror I was moved by an encounter to another location. This location had a clue on it, should I have picked up the clue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question isn't covered in the [Arkham Horror FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/AHfaq.pdf). The rule book lists two different ways of picking up Clue tokens. The first is when you end your movement in a location that contains a Clue token, or when a Clue token is placed in your location from a Mythos card. I think that if you were moved to a location with a Clue token you could claim it, but it isn't definitive in my mind. **Edit:** some discussion on [BGG](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/5732912#5732912) indicate that this was probably an oversight, and will likely be corrected in the forthcomming FAQv2. This is similar to how the Mythos collection of Clue token was corrected in later versions of the rulebook and in the current FAQ. This is just conjecture at this point though, so officially you cannot collect Clue tokens after being moved via an enounter.

In the [rulebook](http://www.math.iupui.edu/~bramsey/AH_Rules.pdf) under **Phase II: Movement** (page 8):

> **Picking Up Clues** - Any time an investigator ends his movement in a location that contains Clue tokens, he may immediately take any or all of those Clue tokens. The investigator may not take any Clue tokens if he merely moves through the location and then continues his movement: He must end his movement in the location containing the Clue tokens.

Later on in the instructions under **Phase V: Mythos** (page 10):

> **Place Clue Token** - Most mythos cards indicate a location where a Clue token appears. Place a Clue token on the indicated location unless there is an open gate there. If one or more investigators are at that location, one of them (they should decide among themselves) may immediately take that Clue token. If the players cannot agree on who gets the Clue token, the first player decides

Comment: What BGG discussion are you trying to link to? Even after correcting the misspelling in the link, it points to a totally different game.

Comment: @EvilAmarant7x, it was a typo on my part. Several threads exist on BGG, so I linked to another one. This one mentions the designer at GenCon playimg with the pick up Clue tokens at the end of each Phase. Officially you do not collect Clue tokens this way, but there is mounting evidence that this might soon change.

Answer (score 4):

**No**.  In order to pick up a clue token, you must end your movement in that space.  Since the encounters is after the movement phase, it is too late to end your movement there, and the clue remains.  Where you to stay there next turn, you could then pick up the clue.

Comment: While this makes sense given a strict reading of the rules, it's really not clear that it's what they meant to happen, especially given that you *do* get clue tokens that appear during the mythos phase.

Comment: I agree that it could be contrary to their intent;  however, as I lack any meaningful way to know their intent, I tend to fall back on the exact wording of the rules.  If there's a customer-service reply or a blog post or something contradicting these rules, I'm all ears. :)

Comment: This answer is the most correct, since the release of the official FAQ v2.0 (Dec 5, 2012) (see **the complete FAQ** near the bottom of http://fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite_sec.asp?eidm=6&esem=4).  Near the bottom (left side) of page 4, it states:  "Note that investigators **do not pick up any Clue tokens when** they are sent to a location with a Clue token during the Upkeep Phase, **the Arkham Encounters Phase**, or the Other World Encounters Phase."